# Fedora can't properly load a .ovpn file (openVPN configuration file)

Tags: fedora, networkmanager, openvpn

When trying to use a .ovpn file in Fedora it doesn't load the certificates correctly. It opens the file, but all the certificate spaces are empty and I can't load anything into them. I can manually tear apart the file to create the individual cert files, but that is time consuming and only a cheap workaround. The same file works on my Android devices, so I know the .ovpn file is good. I've seen the same problem in Slackware so it isn't a Fedora-specific problem, but being that I use Fedora I tagged it as such. Anyone know what can be done to fix this?

I can't upload the file but I pasted the text of it here. The IP address and keys are heavily edited so you won't be able to actually use the file for anything, but it can still be loaded as an openvpn configuration if you want to see what it does. Just save the contents as filename.ovpn.

The .ovpn file is generated by the OpenVPN function on my home router.

http://pastebin.com/vAyyPeZg

Comment: You appear to have disclosed your private key. I hope that was a example CA, certificate & key you generated just to post that, if not you need to immediately revoke the certificate and update your CRLs.

Comment: I overwrote large chunks of it with random nonsense. It isn't usable for anything.

Comment: NetworkManager-openvpn has some support for importing those files but it's by no means perfect. Have you checked that the file works at least when used directly with OpenVPN?

Comment: I am having the same issue on Fedora 21. I haven't found a fix, but one work-around is to create a VPN connection as root with the command `sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn` (where `client.ovpn` is the OpenVPN client profile downloaded from the server).

Answer (score 5):

This is a known bug with NetworkManager, and it's been open since October 2010:

- https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=633337

It does not seem likely that NetworkManager will be able to import .ovpn files any time soon. Given this, you have two alternatives:

1. Use the following command instead: `sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn`. This works for me in Fedora 21.
2. Break apart the .ovpn file and separate out the keys yourself, then put them in the right fields. I found instructions to do that at https://naveensnayak.wordpress.com/2013/03/04/ubuntu-openvpn-with-ovpn-file/. This works under Fedora 21 as long as you first [disable SELinux with the command](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/31983/solved-openvpn-does-not-work-activation-of-network-connection-failed/) `sudo setenforce 1` or reset the SELinux permissions on the certificates as with `mkdir ~/.cert ; mv *.crt ~/.cert ; restorecon -R -v ~/.cert` (see [this answer on Fedora's Ask server](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/31989/there-is-a-conflict-between-selinux-and-openvpn-connection/?answer=32033#post-id-32033)) .

   - Create a file called `ca.crt` – copy the text between `<ca>` and `</ca>` from `client.ovpn` into this file
   - Create a file called `client.crt` – copy the text between `<cert>` and `</cert>` from `client.ovpn` into this file
   - Create a file called `client.key` – copy the text between `<key>` and `</key>` from `client.ovpn` into this file
   - Create a file called `ta.key` – copy the text between `<tls-auth>` and `</tls-auth>` from `client.ovpn` into this file

In `client.ovpn`, on the line just before `## —–BEGIN RSA SIGNATURE—–`, add the following lines:

```
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
tls-auth ta.key
```

After importing the .ovpn file, you'll need to add your username and password, and also need to click on **Advanced** and go to the **TLS Authentication** tab. Ensure that **Key file** is set to `ta.key`. **Key Direction** must be set based on the key direction in your `client.ovpn` file: open `client.ovpn` and search for `key-direction` and note the number after that (mine is `1`).